# Understanding Screen Position Node in Unity Shader Graph

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I'm struggling to understand what exactly the Screen Position node outputs in Unity's Shader Graph.

I'm using the screen position with scene depth to calculate the distance between two objects.

Every tutorial I saw ([like Brackey's forcefield one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiOGWZXBg4Y&t=302s)) is using the **alpha channel** of the Screen Position output:

[image: Screengrab from Brackey's tutorial showing how Screen Position node is used]

I read that the Screen Position node outputs the mesh vertex screen positions.

- Does it means the 2D position on the screen projection?
- Or the vertex 3D position from the eye space?
- And more importantly, what is exactly the apha channel of this output? (I have the feeling this is related to the "clip space W component" [in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@8.2/manual/Screen-Position-Node.html))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like when the Screen Position mode is **in the "Raw" mode** as used in the tutorial you linked, it's giving you the same result as you'd get from this shader...

```
struct v2f {
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
    float4 screenPosition : TEXCOORD0;
}

v2f vert (appdata v) {
    v2f o;
    // This is effectively a multiplication by the Model-View-Projection matrix,
    // taking the vertex from object space to clip space (before the perspective divide)
    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

    // This copies the information from the "special" vertex position semantic that in
    // older shader models we can't read directly in the fragment shader. Copying it out
    // lets us interpolate it and read it just like any other texture coordinate.
    o.screenPosition = o.vertex;
    return o;
}

fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
    // Here we get the per-pixel value, after it's been
    // interpolated between the three vertices in the triangle.
    float4 shift = i.screenPosition;

    // Ordinarily, 0,0 would be the center of the screen, but Unity calls 
    // that mode "Center" not "Raw". In Raw mode, the center of the screen is 0.5
    shift.xy += 0.5f;
    return shift;
}
```

In this `screenPosition` value, the 4th component of the vector, "**w**" (or "Alpha / a" when you think of the vector as an RGBA colour), is the easiest to understand: **it's the world-space depth** of the pixel being drawn, measured from the camera, along its viewing axis. (Also called **eye-space depth**)

The x, y, and z components have been mangled by the projection in a way that makes them a bit more complicated to explain, so I'll attack them separately:

If we do "the perspective divide" on **x and y**, dividing them by the depth w, this brings them into normalized device coordinates, telling us **where the pixel sits within our rendering viewport**. x/w = -1 is the left edge, x/w = 0 is the center, and x/w = 1 is the right edge. Likewise for y/w along the vertical. The further away a point is in depth, the more it gets crunched-in by this perspective divide, creating the effect where objects appear smaller as they move further away.

The values before the division are related to the eye-space position of the point, scaled according to the horizontal and vertical field of view, and occasionally shifted if we're using an oblique frustum. Suffice it to say, they're "whatever we need them to be so that the perspective divide puts them into the right place on the screen" - it's usually not very meaningful to operate on these values before the division.

Note that in the Unity Shader graph node these x and y values have been shifted to keep (0.5, 0.5) at the center of the screen, presumably so that if you're using this to map a texture in screen space, it stays centered by default.

**The z component** has a different mangling applied, to handle **clipping against the near and far planes**, at z = -1 and z = 1 respectively. Values between these extremes are non-linearly distributed, and end up getting mapped to the **values we use for depth-testing** the fragment and ultimately **writing into the depth buffer**.

This non-linear z is useful for depth buffering, but not very intuitive for our purposes, which is why Unity includes macros and shader nodes that automatically decode it back to linear, world-space/eye-space depth for our convenience.

---

This node also has other modes:

- **Default:** post perspective divide, and scaled/shifted so that x, y = (0, 0) is the bottom-left of the screen, (1, 1) is the top-right
- **Center:** post-perspective divide, with no scale/shift, so x, y = (0, 0) is the center of the screen (-1, -1) is the bottom-left, and (1, 1) is the top-right
- **Tiled:** like Center, but with the negative coordinates wrapped, so the values go from (0, 0) to (1, 1) over each quadrant of the screen.

Comment: Wow, great answer! It answers a lot of questions even if I need more read to fully understand the concept. I have the feeling that with orthographic camera, the W value would be always 1? Or at least constant?

Comment: That would be a sensible way to do it. It's worth checking whether the screen position w is usable for this effect in an orthographic view. If not, you might need to harvest the depth in a different way.

Comment: It seems z and w are both depth value, a little bit confued...

Comment: Interesting explanation, so if we multiply vertex with Model-View matrix (excluding projection) and take the Z value it will be the same as screenPosition.w ?

Answer (score 0):

I might not have completely gotten your question , so ill give you what i would be contemplating.

Everything starts of in screen space , meaning everything is 2D to begin with ,
your primitives are rasterised and the depth(normalized) is calculated implicitly based on the z of the primitive coordinates .

When you apply transformation matrices(MVP) onto your primitive , stuff like perspective divide ,view and model-space transformations happen on the initial primitives to give the end transformed result(which is the generic 3D object).

I don't know from a Unity stand point but it might be that an inverse of Projection matrix is multiplied to the MVP(witch means you remove the P from MVP) ,to give you the vertex coordinates with no perspective.

Sorry English is not that great.